# Slide in from left hidden div inside a parent div (multiple div’s with same class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I have multiple div’s with multiple hidden divs. I want to display each of this div is on a link hover.

My issue is that code seems to display and hide all hidden div’s at ones. I want only to display the hidden div inside the parent of link that trigged the hover.

Seems a bit bad explanation so let me put it this way. Lets say there are 10 div’s and someone hover the link inside div 1 I want only to display the hidden div inside div no 1.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 posts">
  <div class="div-hidden"> 

    <!-- hidden content here --> 

  </div>
  <span class="thumbnail text-center"> <img src="imge" alt="">
  <h3>Titile</h3>
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <hr class="line">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> <a href="" class="fa fa-heart-o"></a> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> <a href="" class="fa fa-eye show-hidden"></a> </div>
  </div>
  </span> </div>

<Script>        
   $(function() {
    $('.div-hidden').hide();
    $('.show-hidden').hover(function() {

    $('.div-hidden').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400); 

    });

    $('.show-hidden').mouseout(function() { 

    $('.div-hidden').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400); 

    });

});     
</script>
```

Also i tried using `$(this)` in the the code which made the code stop working.

```
$(this).('.div-hidden').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);
```

Appreciate your time and input.

Comment: please provide html of link that you are want to use to display hidden div

Comment: You should elaborate on how you tried using `$(this)`, and what happened exactly. (Because it seems like you indeed need `this` to only apply the effect to the element that was hovered, not every element with the class `div-hidden`, which your current code does.)

Comment: @doldt i used it as `$(this).('.div-hidden').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);`

Comment: @TalhaAbrar link is in the code `<a href="" class="fa fa-eye show-hidden"></a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$(this).closest('div.posts')
        .find('.div-hidden').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);
```

OR

```
$(this).parent().parent().
        .parent().parent()
         .find('.div-hidden').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 400);
```

Answer (score 1):

First why when you hover all div's are hidden at once ? I suppose that each div have the same identifier `.div-hidden`. When you select this class you always select all the divs with this class attributed. Why don't you identify each of your div with a unique identifier with an `id` and then hide/show them on hover ?  The parent of link that trigged the hover has a unique identifier to query with a CSS selector ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents('.posts').find('.div-hidden').show();
```